# Double loop - cycling through subfolders and files for consolidation

Tags: excel, vba, nested-loops

I am a bit stuck with finishing the script below. 
I got to this point and it does the basic thing I need it to do but it does need a bit of tweaking to get perfect.

It does the following: 1-pickup and prep master output file; 2- open each file in folder 'xls' and copy data from the designated sheet at the end of the master output file; 3-final edit of the master file; 4-save master file with name based on the input archives.

Where I need help is and was unable to fix up is: I want the script to cycle through subfolders in 'xls' folder and create a single master for each subfolder in 'xls' collecting data from files in that subfolder and name it after subfolder.

I understand I need another loop for subfolders but I am not really good with dirs in vba. Would this require a major overhaul?

```
Sub Joiner()

'Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

Dim folderPath As String
Dim FileNAME As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim NewSht As Worksheet
Dim FindRng As Range
Dim PasteRow As Long
Dim DayVar As String
Dim RangeVar As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Targetsh As Worksheet
Dim RecordsCount As Long


' set master workbook
Workbooks.Open FileNAME:="C:\TA\output\Master Template.xlsx"
Set Masterwb = Workbooks("Master Template.xlsx")
Set Targetsh = Masterwb.Sheets("Data")

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        .Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "SysTime"
        .Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "Seq#"
        .Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "A1"
        .Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "F2"
        .Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "F3"
        .Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "T4"
        .Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "T5"
        .Range("H1").FormulaR1C1 = "T6"
        .Range("I1").FormulaR1C1 = "T7"
        .Range("J1").FormulaR1C1 = "T8"
        .Range("K1").FormulaR1C1 = "A9"
        .Range("A1:K1").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A1:K1").Interior.ColorIndex = 19

        .Range("L1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
        .Range("M1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date/Seq#"

    End With


folderPath = "C:\TA\xls\" 'contains folder path

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileNAME = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls*")
Do While FileNAME <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & FileNAME)
    'DayVar = Left(Right(wb.Name, 13), 8)

    LastRow = wb.Sheets("Cleaned").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    RangeVar = wb.Sheets("Cleaned").Range("A2:K" & LastRow)


    Targetsh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(RangeVar, 1), UBound(RangeVar, 2)) = RangeVar

    wb.Close False

Exit_Loop:
    Set wb = Nothing
    FileNAME = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With Masterwb.Sheets("Data")
        .Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    End With

    LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

        .Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=INT(C1)"
        .Range("M2").FormulaR1C1 = "=C12&""-""&C2"
    End With


    Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2" & ":L" & LastRow)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns("L:L").Cells = .Columns("L:L").Cells.Value
    End With

    Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2" & ":M" & LastRow)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns("M:M").Cells = .Columns("M:M").Cells.Value
    End With

    With Masterwb.Sheets("Data")
        .Range(Range("L2"), Range("L2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With


    'Name the master output based on id
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim InterName As String
    Dim FinalName As String
    Dim FilePath As String

    FirstName = Dir("C:TA\Input\*.cab", vbNormal)
    InterName = "Master Template " & Right(Left(FirstName, 12), 4)

    'MsgBox FirstName
    'MsgBox InterName


    FilePath = "C:\TA\output"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileNAME:=FilePath & "\" & InterName & ".xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False



    '

End Sub
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Do you have only one level of subfolders or many ?

Comment: Hi Patel. only one level of subs. So xls folder has a lot of subfolders and each is having a lot of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Patel!
I used your solution to complement my current vba snippet. 
It may be a bit clunky but it does what I need it to do. 
Thank you.

Posting a solution below for the benefit of the community.

```
Sub MassJoiner()
'this is a version of joiner with subfolders

'Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

Dim folderPath As String
Dim FileNAME As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim NewSht As Worksheet
Dim FindRng As Range
Dim PasteRow As Long
Dim DayVar As String
Dim RangeVar As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Targetsh As Worksheet
Dim RecordsCount As Long
Dim StrFile As String
Dim mFolder As String

Dim BatchCount As Long
Dim ID As String

   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   mFolder = "D:\TA\TEST\" ' path to change
   Set mainFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(mFolder)
   StrFile = Dir(mFolder & "*.xls*")



    BatchCount = 0

    Workbooks.Open FileNAME:="C:\TA\output\Master Template.xlsx"

    For Each mySubFolder In mainFolder.subfolders
     StrFile = Dir(mySubFolder & "\*.xls*")
     Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

    Set Masterwb = Workbooks("Master Template.xlsx")
    Set Targetsh = Masterwb.Sheets("Data")

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        .Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "SysTime"
        .Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "Seq#"
        .Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "A1"
        .Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "F2"
        .Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "F3"
        .Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "T4"
        .Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "T5"
        .Range("H1").FormulaR1C1 = "T6"
        .Range("I1").FormulaR1C1 = "T7"
        .Range("J1").FormulaR1C1 = "T8"
        .Range("K1").FormulaR1C1 = "A9"
        .Range("A1:K1").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A1:K1").Interior.ColorIndex = 19

        .Range("L1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
        .Range("M1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date/Seq# pair"

    End With






'FileNAME = Dir(folderPath & "*.xls*")
'Do While FileNAME <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(mySubFolder & "\" & StrFile)
    'DayVar = Left(Right(wb.Name, 13), 8)

    LastRow = wb.Sheets("Cleaned").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    RangeVar = wb.Sheets("Cleaned").Range("A2:K" & LastRow)


    Targetsh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(RangeVar, 1), UBound(RangeVar, 2)) = RangeVar

    wb.Close False

'Exit_Loop:
'    Set wb = Nothing
'    FileNAME = Dir
'Loop

    StrFile = Dir
    Loop


    With Masterwb.Sheets("Data")
        .Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    End With

    LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        .Range("M2").FormulaR1C1 = "Date/Seq# pair"
        .Range("m2").FormulaR1C1 = "=C12&""-""&C2"
    End With


    Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2" & ":L" & LastRow)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns("L:L").Cells = .Columns("L:L").Cells.Value
    End With

    Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2" & ":M" & LastRow)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns("M:M").Cells = .Columns("M:M").Cells.Value
    End With

    With Masterwb.Sheets("Data")
        .Range(Range("l2"), Range("l2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With


    'Name the master output based on job id
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim InterName As String
    Dim FinalName As String
    Dim FilePath As String

    FirstName = mySubFolder
    InterName = "Master Template " & Right(FirstName, 4)
    ID = Right(FirstName, 4)

    'MsgBox FirstName
    'MsgBox InterName


    FilePath = "C:\TA\output"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileNAME:=FilePath & "\" & InterName & ".xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    BatchCount = BatchCount + 1

    Application.Speech.Speak "Batch job" & BatchCount & "finalized. ID" & ID

    Workbooks.Open FileNAME:="C:\output\Master Template.xlsx"


    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can list excel files in a folder and subfolders

```
Sub ListSubfoldersFile() ' only one level subfolders
   arow = 2
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   mFolder = "F:\Download\" ' path to change
   Set mainFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(mFolder)
   StrFile = Dir(mFolder & "*.xls*")
   Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
     Cells(arow, 1).Value = mFolder & StrFile
     arow = arow + 1
     StrFile = Dir
   Loop
   For Each mySubFolder In mainFolder.subfolders
     StrFile = Dir(mySubFolder & "\*.xls*")
     Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Cells(arow, 1).Value = mySubFolder & "\" & StrFile
        arow = arow + 1
        StrFile = Dir
     Loop
   Next
End Sub
```